how to access remote branch locally?
I'm new to this Git and GitHub thing, and I'm having this confusion.
So, there are multiple people in my project, and they all work in their own branch (but we all work in the same file/module).
File
 |-----branch 1
 |-----branch 2
 |-----branch 3
 ...

I want to check my friends' work, so I do git pull. But it did not bring all of the branches to my local repository. Then I read that instead of git pull, you have to do git fetch, so I tried git fetch origin. But it did nothing, it does not give any output in the terminal. When I tried git branch, it still only shows my main branch. Then, I tried git branch -a or git branch -r it does show all of the branches, but I could not access it on my local repository, if I do git checkout <branch name> it would switch to the branch but the there's nothing in it (I'm assuming it just makes a new branch instead of switching to the already exist branch).
How to make your remote branch be accessible on your local repository?

git switch or git checkout do not create branches unless you use the -c/-b option. Your teammates might not have pushed their changes to their branches

@mousetail they already push their changes, and i could see it on my github repo (on website)

Have you maybe preciously created local branches with those names? Try git switch --detach origin/branch-name

The remote branches are all there locally. What do you mean by "make accessible"? Do you want to review their branch? Do you want to test what they did? Do you want to know what happens when you integrate ("merge") their work with your work?

Take a look at Git Branching - Remote Branches.

@mousetail you don't need -c or -b to create local copies of remote tracking branches. The command OP ran should work just fine.

If the branch already existed without content you would just switch to it. Delete your local copy and try to check it out again. (Or use @mousetail's suggestion of checking out the origin/branch-name for testing.) Also, the reason git fetch showed nothing is probably because you did it right after git pull which also did a fetch behind the scenes, so you fetched twice in a row.

@TTT Yes that's what I meant. They would not create empty branches and instead use the branches the teammates pushed

@mousetail Ah OK. I didn't read it that way in the context of the question but I see what you mean now.

Assuming that your remote is called origin and that the refspsec for remote.origin.fetch is +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*, when you've run the command git fetch, you've fetched all the branches from the remote.
At this point, all the branches on the remote that weren't present in your repository are under refs/remotes/origin/ as tracking branches. This means that if someone was working on a branch called my_feature, you would find said branch under refs/remotes/origin/my_feature.
If you want to inspect a tracking branch, you need to run:
git checkout origin/my_feature

When you were attempting git checkout <branch name>, you were trying to switch to a topic branch, not a tracking branch. Topic branches are located under refs/heads/, while tracking branches are under refs/remotes/origin/.
Once you checkout a tracking branch, Git will enter the detached HEAD state. In this state, you can read your colleague's work and even make commits, but beware. When in the detached HEAD state, the HEAD ref is not pointing to a topic branch, but to a specific commit. If you make any commits in this scenario, as soon as you checkout a branch, all of your work in the detached HEAD state will be lost. So, if you're interested in the changes you're seeing, make sure to create a topic branch from the tracking branch with either git switch -c my_feature or git checkout -b my_feature.
Here is also a good article from Baeldung about the detached HEAD state, if you want to deepen the topic.
Disclaimer: when I said that you could make commits in the detached HEAD state after checking out a tracking branch, that was meant in general as in what you're capable of in the detached HEAD state and in what are the risks. It was merely meant as a brief introduction to the detached HEAD state. As a matter of fact, you should not work on a tracking branch. Tracking branches are only meant for tracking the work on a remote branch. If you want to make changes, you should work on a topic branch. In your case, one created from a tracking branch.

Answer to the comment

so what git fetch do is fecthing branch from remote to my local repo as a tracking branch? not a local branch?

git fetch downloads your remote's branches as tracking branches.

You say that I should not work on a tracking branch, then, is there a way so that I be able to do edit/work on branch that my friends made?

If you want to work on a branch, you need to work on a topic (local) branch. You can create a topic branch from a tracking branch like so:
# fetching the branch from the remote
git fetch origin <branch>

# checking out the tracking branch with the changes from the remote
git checkout origin/<branch> 

# opening the source codes and inspecting changes

# if you like the changes, you can create a topic branch from the tracking branch currently checked out
git checkout -b <branch>

# Alternatively, if this is not your first fetch and there is already a topic branch for your tracking branch,
# you can checkout the topic branch and merge the tracking branch into it

# checkout the topic branch associated to the tracking branch
git checkout <branch>

# merging the remote's changes into your local branch
git merge origin/<branch>

Keep in mind that once you've created a topic branch from a tracking branch, you shouldn't be working on it if other people are working on its remote counterpart. What you want to do is to take advantage of Git's branching functionality, and create a new branch diverging from the newly created topic branch. This is because if you and your colleague work on a same branch, the two of you will add a different history of changes. So, when both of you will push your changes, the second person pushing will see their changes rejected, as the history on the same branch has diverged. Instead, by creating a new branch, you will work on a different line of development that can be always pushed to a new remote's branch and that can be later merged into your colleague's branch (or vice versa).
In fact, I personally think that merging two different topic branches is easier than re-aligning the history of a branch. In both cases you'll have to perform a merge, possibly with conflicts. But in the first case, you can create a pull request and have different people from your team helping you to resolve the conflicts. While, in the second case, the person who saw their changes being rejected is more on their own and needs to:

Fetch the changes of the other person from the remote git fetch origin <branch>
Checkout the corresponding local branch git checkout <branch>
Merge the other person's history into the local history git merge origin/<branch>
Re-attempt a push git push origin <branch>


so what git fetch do is fecthing branch from remote to my local repo as a tracking branch? not a local branch? You say that I should not work on a tracking branch, then, is there a way so that I be able to do edit/work on branch that my friends made? @dani-vta

@aki I have improved my answer

While creating a new branch locally with git checkout, you can specify a remote branch to track.
The command is git checkout -b <local-branch-name> remotes/origin/<remote-branch-name>
In the above command, origin refers to the remote repo's name in local.

Git checkout has been deprecated for several years now. You really shouldn't be recommending it anymore. Use git switch
